# oNode being Set to Nothing, but why, and how do I fix it?

Tags: date, datetime, xpath, vbscript, msxml

I am trying to develop a token (in this case a piece of code that runs inside a bigger VBScript) that returns information from an XML that is supplied by the 3rd-party software to a word plugin using bookmarks to provide parameters to the tokens.

So here is what is going on,

```
XmlDoc.SetProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"

ReturnData = vbNullString

Public Function GetParameterXml()
    GetParameterXml = _
    "<Parameters>" & _
        "<Parameter Value='Last_Hearing' Code='L' Description='Last_Hearing' Type='Combo'>" & _
            "<Options>" & _
                "<Option Code='' Description='True' Value='True' />" & _
                "<Option Code='' Description='False' Value='False' />" & _
            "</Options>" & _
        "</Parameter>" & _
    "</Parameters>"     
End Function

Dim oNode : Set oNode = XmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("/Record/CelloXml/Integration/Case/Hearing/Setting/CourtroomMinutes/Comment")
Dim lastHearing : Set lastHearing = Parameters.Item( BookMark, "Last_Hearing" )     

If IsNull(lastHearing) Then
    lastHearing = False
End If
stop
If lastHearing.Value = "True" Then
    Dim dateNodes : Set dateNodes = XmlDoc.SelectNodes("/Record/CelloXml/Integration/Case/Hearing/Setting/HearingDate")
    Dim mostRecentHearingDate
    Dim dateNode
    Dim todaysDate
    todaysDate = Date

    Dim dateList : Set dateList = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
    For Each dateNode In dateNodes
        dateList.Add CDate(dateNode.Text)
    Next
    dateList.Sort()

    Dim tempDate
    For Each tempDate In dateList
        If tempDate < todaysDate Then
            mostRecentHearingDate = tempDate
        End If
    Next
    mostRecentHearingDate = CStr(mostRecentHearingDate)
    Set oNode = XmlDoc.selectSingleNode("/Record/CelloXml/Integration/Case/Hearing/Setting[HearingDate/text()='" & mostRecentHearingDate & "']/CourtroomMinutes/Comment")
End If

If Not oNode Is Nothing Then
    ReturnData = oNode.text
Else
    ReturnData = vbNullString
End If
```

Everything works the way that I want it to up until

```
Set oNode = XmlDoc.selectSingleNode("/Record/CelloXml/Integration/Case/Hearing/Setting[HearingDate/text()='" & mostRecentHearingDate & "']/CourtroomMinutes/Comment")
```

I needed `dateList` to hold dates(or date literals) because I assumed that I would get a bad sort if I tried to sort the dates as a string rather than an actual date,  so I converted the text from the node to a date(or date literal) and added it to `dateList`

When I was done with all the calculations then I needed a string to run in my XPath, if I hard code the date(as a string{08/05/2014}) into the XPath query it works, but when I turn `mostRecentHearingDate` into a string using `CStr` then `oNode` is Set to Nothing

**The Node exists and holds data**

So,

- Why is this happening?
- How do I get it to function the way I think it should?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do

```
dim mostRecentHearingDate
mostRecentHearingDate = CDate("08/05/2014")
mostRecentHearingDate = CStr(mostRecentHearingDate)
```

mostRecentHearingDate = "8/5/2014"  not "08/05/2014" it drops the leading "0"

try

```
mostRecentHearingDate = Right("0"&DatePart("m",mostRecentHearingDate),2) & "/" & Right("0"&DatePart("d",mostRecentHearingDate),2) &  "/" & DatePart("YYYY",mostRecentHearingDate)
```

That yields

```
08/05/2014
```

Comment: OMGOSH! can't believe I didn't see that. is there no other way to remedy this than that long ugly string?

Comment: There could be something more efficient but basically you have to pad with leading "0"

Comment: what I was trying before what just removing the Date Literal Symbols (`#`) and replacing them with nothing, and that wasn't working either

Comment: You did not provide an xml sample, maybe that will help

Comment: doing a `Replace(mostRecentHearingDate, "#", "")` also strips the zeros. Your answer is correct and fixes the issue. I saw the right date and paid no attention to the missing zeros.  Thank you

Comment: you could try [`FormatDateTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8aebkz6s(v=vs.84).aspx) with vbShortDate instead of `CStr()`, but this is dependent on your regional settings